# I want to give a space along with value

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a question about python string.

I'm trying to make a `wx.listbox`, and I want to input 2 items.

In this case can't I give a space between 2 string and integer?

```
for item in test():
    self.Append('%s  %d'%(str(item.name), item.cnt))
```

I want to give a gap between %s and %d using variable.

Comment: That will generate a space between the data from the two variables. Please show us the output of that and what `item.name` and `item.cnt` are.

Comment: You mean something like `"%s%s%d" %(item.name, ' '*n, item.cnt)` ? (Where `n` is the number of spaces you want)

Comment: OK, play fair. TWO lines of code and we are supposed to divine the rest? You can see people want to help you, give them a chance and edit the question. Specifically, the following information might be useful.

1. You complain that a gap isn't appearing. Where and between what do you imagine you would see a gap?

2. You appear to have extracted a method from a class. Would it be too much to ask to see the code of the whole class?

Sorry to seem picky, but the more information you can provide the more likely it is someone will be able to help (which is why we are here, right?)

Comment: I tried and its coming with space 
`>>> '%s  %d'% ('test', 50)`

`'test  50'`

Comment: Did you try to put a tabulation instead of a space ? `'%s\t%d'`

Comment: @holdenweb some just ask a question and leave it there to check it some other day...

Comment: @zhangxaochen in which case I shall be interested to learn the answer to my question when they return.

Answer (score 1):

The space **is** there, maybe just not quite visible, you may need something like `str.ljust` to make the appended strings *aligned*. E.g.:

```
In [14]: for i, s in enumerate(['name', 'looongname']):
    ...:     print '%s%d'%(s.ljust(20), i)
#prints out:
name                0
looongname          1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to join two strings just use the join-function. There you can choose what to use between the strings:

```
' '.join([(str(item.name), item.cnt])
```

You can put everything between the quotes.